# Freebsd 9.2 + Apache24 + php55-5.5.10 - Apache is not loading the PHP extensions

Tags: php, apache, freebsd

I'm Apache24 + PHP55, extensions are in the directory but not load on Apache.
The extensions are in the directory: /usr/local/etc/php/extensions.ini. Even in php_info() including the file, extensions are not loaded.

Someone is having the same problem?

```
kamihouse# service apache24 configtest
Performing sanity check on apache24 configuration:
Syntax OK
kamihouse# 
kamihouse# 
kamihouse# apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.9 (FreeBSD)
Server built:   Apr  1 2014 22:36:46
kamihouse# 
kamihouse# 
kamihouse# /usr/local/bin/php-cgi -v
PHP 5.5.10 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Apr  1 2014 23:18:48)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
kamihouse# 
kamihouse# 
kamihouse# php -v
PHP 5.5.10 (cli) (built: Apr  1 2014 23:18:45) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
kamihouse# 
kamihouse# 
kamihouse# apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.9 (FreeBSD)
Server built:   Apr  1 2014 22:36:46
kamihouse#
```

Comment: What does `php -m` tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with version **PHP55-5.5.10** for **Apache24** on **FreeBSD 9+** is necessary to include the module *ports/www/mod_php55*

Settings (make config) both *ports/lang/php55* and *ports/www/mod_php55* should be the same.

Then just build *ports/lang/php55-extensions*